# git: having trouble privileges

Tags: git

I have a web project I'm developing, and I want to push it to a remote with my username, like `ssh://myUserName@remote:/home/someOtherUser/project.git`.

The problem is I that I want to push the project inside another user's home directory.

I start getting error of permissions and `project.git/hooks/post-receive` does not fire (I had to execute it manually) and my web project dose not respond on the browser until I change the ownership of `public_html/*` to its user;

what I understood :

- I push the project then I get errors of permission but yet the project was pushed and it is on the server
- the hook `post-receive` did not fire so I had to go as root and fire it
- when I fire `post-receive` as root, the files 'checkedout' (from the `.git` to `public_html`) are owned by `root` so the user where we are (`/home/someUser/project.git`) does not have permission to use these files 'checkedout'
- so I do a `chown -R someUser:someUser *` inside the `public_html`to solve the problem

How Can I solve this?

Comment: file permissions are a feature, not a problem. If you need to push into a directory, make sure you have the rights to do so. "Pushing into another user's home dir" is almost certainly a bad idea. It shouldn't be *their home directory* if *your user* can write to it. Simple as that.

Comment: I can manage to put the `.git` directory in my home directory but would `post-receive` still work?